# Getting proper unix timestamp with JS for facebook scheduler

Tags: javascript, facebook, momentjs

I'm trying to make scheduled posts to Facebook with the PHP SDK (normal posts are working fine, just issues with scheduling)

I use dropdowns for date and time choices which I retrieve and use Moments.js to get the Unix timestamp of:

```
    var year = document.getElementById("selectYear").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("selectMonth").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("selectDay").value;
    var time = document.getElementById("selectTime").value;

    //in this example month is 1 day is 1 year is 2019 and time is 09:00:00

    var timeStamp = ( moment(month + '-' + day + '-' + year + '-' + time).unix() )*1000
```

However, when I make the call I get the Facebook PHP SDK Error #100: The specified scheduled publish time is invalid

Is this not the proper unix timestamp?

Comment: You are multiplying it by 1000, which makes it not a Unix time stamp anymore. Javascript keeps time in ms, but Unix in seconds.

Comment: so I should only be multiplying by 100 in javascript?

Comment: You don't need to multiply it by anything.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying

Comment: ha worked perfectly! Thanks! If you want to make that into an answer I'll go ahead and accept it for you

Comment: My pleasure! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Unix time stamp counts the seconds since 1970. Javascript does the same, but in milliseconds.

You are multiplying the output of unix() by 1000, effectively creating a timestamp you can easily handle in JS, but it's not a Unix timestamp anymore. Just don't do that multiplication and you should be fine.